# Error while reading VTK files in Paraview/VisIt

Tags: vtk, paraview

I have been getting the following error while opening a `.vtk` file in Paraview:

"Error reading ascii data. Possible mismatch of datasize with declaration."

I am running a simulation on my Mac OS X 10.9.3, and saving my solution files in `.vtk` format. While the initial solution file (at time t=0) opens perfectly, the above error occurs with the next few solution files. Moreover, some of my scalar variables disappear from the data-set in Paraview. I tried opening the file on my friends laptop, which has a Linux OS, and Paraview opens all the files correctly with all variables in place. I noticed a similar problem while using VisIT.

I have even tried to use different versions of Paraview but the problem persists. Could there be a problem with the *vtkreader*? Any help or leads to solving this issue will be much appreciated.

PS: I have found a similar post on this forum, but no one seems to have replied to it yet:
[Paraview "possible mismatch of datasize with declaration" error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23814541/paraview-possible-mismatch-of-datasize-with-declaration-error)

Comment: We really need to see the data file to see what could be the problem.

Comment: This is an example of a file which gives this error:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/w8gpr42uvy9yh18/sol0072.vtk

On paraview I can only see the variables Temperature, Pressure and Velocity, while variables like Density and Mach number are not displayed even though they are explicitly present in the file

Comment: This is another example of a solution file which stores just one variable "convar". I am simulating a linear advection problem. Everything displays well till file no.22, but form file n0. 23 onward (https://www.dropbox.com/s/vq8imuhuh5p60io/sol0023.vtk), everything goes haywire. I get a similar error and the range of the variable seems to blow up. Once again I tested this on a linux system and it displays everything correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Your file declares 70970 points although I think that it has 70971.

Your file declares 140760 cells although I think that it has 140761.